# Have you got a job yet?

Tags: meaning

> Have you got a job yet?

Does this setentene mean

1. Do you have a job already? or 2. Did you already succeed to get a job?

Comment: **Have you already succeeded in getting** a job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Have you got a job yet?

This is asking if a person's job search has succeed. It implies that the person addressed was out of a job previously, and has been attempting to get one. It is not asking if the person already has a job. It might be used when the person has never had a job, and is looking for a first job. Or it might be used when a person has left or been discharged from a previous job, and is looking for a new one.